# Detect change in RadGrid item expand/collapse state

Tags: c#, radgrid

I have a RadGrid displaying a hierarchical structure.  I want to save the expand/collapse state of each item in the grid so that when the user returns to the site, everything looks exactly as they left it.  I have code to save and restore the state of expanded/collapsed items, however, I now need a way to detect which item is currently being expanded/collapsed when the user clicks on the expand/collapse icon.  I know there's a command event, but there is no command argument nor does there seem to be any indication of which item's state is being changed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that the GridCommandEventArgs passed into the RadGrid.ItemCommand event contains an 'Item' property that represents the item that was expanded/collapsed.  If casted to a GridDataItem, one can retrieve the data key and do whatever manipulation is necessary.

```
protected void RadGrid_OnItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if(e.CommandName.Equals("ExpandCollapse"))
        {
            string id = ((GridDataItem)e.Item).GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString();
            // ... do work on id (i.e. save state, etc.) ...
        }
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // What could possibly go wrong? :)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Persistance Framework.
In my post here:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/persistence-framework/presistenceframework-not-save-groups.aspx#2248287
there is example how to do this.

Comment: While this answer is old and this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.